# What kind of solenoid could be used to engage piano keys like in this example?

Tags: solenoid, music

I was inspired by the video of Mark Rober and the self-playing Edelweiss piano and would like to build and retro fit a similar contraption on my piano.

In the video, a type of solenoid is shown that:

- is in a default state of down (I believe it is using the plunger side of a push solenoid)
- can be fired at varying strengths (perhaps controlled by the amount of voltage?), 127 different levels of force is mentioned

You can see the solenoid in the video here: https://youtu.be/uBEL3YVzMwk?t=279

Two questions:

1. Does anyone know what kind of solenoid that is or have any specifics on what I should be Googling to find it?
2. My background is in software, not electrical/hardware so if anyone has any guides or tutorials for controlling solenoids using a Raspberry Pi it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I came across this great overview of solenoids from Johnson Electric: https://www.johnsonelectric.com/-/media/files/resources-for-engineers/solenoids/solenoids-principle-of-operation.ashx

Comment: google `player piano solenoid`

Comment: I've been Googling around quite a bit and initially was so annoyed by your comment, but  tried it out and was led to so many great examples of what I'm trying to build--thank you @jsotola